# Whats the best way to test android apk apps in an android virtualbox setting in windows 10?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, sandboxing

I have alot of apk's I'd like isolated to test in a sandbox like environment. Is there something like this where I can duplicate the OS like a virtual machine? I want to test these new apk's on Android 8 Oreo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is an excellent Android emulator. You can even drag and drop the APKs in it to automatically install them. I have been using it for many years now.

Comment: Genymotion cost $100+ per month. Not feasible for a hobbyist just messing around.

Comment: Yeahh didn't use to cost anything 1 year ago :(

Comment: Here are some alternatives though. Hope you find something that suits you. https://alternativeto.net/software/genymotion/